# How to gcc compiling for opengl in windows?

Tags: opengl, gcc, dll, hyperlink, lib

i wanted to make .so file, so make project using opengl(glut) in windows.

using "lib, dll and .h" for opengl

```
glut.lib, glut32.lib | glut.dll, glut32.dll | glut.h
```

but appended gcc issues "undefined reference to 'funcion'".

i make the .o(object) file with .so(shared object) file

```
Command : gcc -c -fPIC main.c -o main.o path
```

So I used the command to create the file.

```
Command : gcc -shared -o main.so -fPIC main.c
```

but i can't make .so file

-> Error Code undefined reference to 'funcion'

```
Error : __impg_glClear, __imp_glBegin ... etc
```

How to make .so file with linking to .lib & .dll?

`Environment : Windows 10, OpenGL(glut), VS2015, added the library dependencies(glut32.lib, glu32.lib, opengl32.lib)`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, what's called a *"shared object"* (`.so`) in the Linux and Unix world is a *"Dynamic Linked Library"* (`.dll`) in Windows. The filename extension doesn't matter actually – Windows will load any file that has a valid PE header just fine – but for the sake of convention we shall call it DLLs.

> So I used the command to create the file.
>
> ```
> Command : gcc -shared -o main.dll -fPIC main.c
> ```
>
> but i can't make .dll file

That is, because your linking command does lack something important: Specifying which external libraries to link to. I don't know where in your project or Makefile you though you added the library dependencies, but they certainly don't show up in the link command. To link against a library with GCC a `-l…` parameters must be given for each library.

There are also a few other problems with the way, this command is called. Certainly you want to link the `.o` file that way created in the previous compilation command. And since you already created the code, there's no use (but also no harm) for `-fPIC`.

So I suggest you use this command for linking instead:

```
gcc -shared -o main.dll main.o -lopengl32 -lglut32
```

Comment: Thank's to answer, three issues your answer `1. ok, my project added the library dependencies glut32.lib, glu32.lib, opengl32.lib`   `2. i make to poring .so file for android, so i need to .so file` `3.i trying to your command 'gcc -shared -o main.dll main.o -lopengl32 -lglut32' but appended can not find -glut32(-lopengl32 is ok)`

Comment: @heeyoungeom: If your target is Android, then there's no use for any DLLs you might have loaded into your project anyway. Also you can't use GLUT with Android. Developing a OpenGL application for Android is very different from what you do on Windows or a regular *nix, because you're ultimately going to live in the "Dalvik" runtime environment and live in a GLSurfaceView. Also shared objects are of limited use (only suitable for NDK stuff).

Comment: as i know, .so file can porting android with NDK or JNI. then i make a .so file. i make the multi platform windows and android. how to know you make the multi platform opengl or opengles? thk's to answer